# DNS record not found - Some incoming emails getting through, others aren't

Tags: domain-name-system, email

I'm having quite a lot of problems with a particular domain in that the DNS record doesn't exist according to [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3Aipimagine.com&run=toolpage#). I usually transfer the nameservers over to us but had to leave them where they were. So I pointed MX and A records at our server.

At the moment some emails get through and others dont. I've sent emails from Gmail which get through ok but then other clients are saying they've sent emails but nothing has come through.

This is the domain registrar:
[image]

And this is our server settings:
[image]

Are there any obvious errors there? Something doesn't seem right.

---

I've changed it to this:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you've inadvertently created the MX record for the subdomain. - https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3Amail.ipimagine.com&run=toolpage#

Comment: @joeqwerty I've amended the settings - it's passes the MX test at the root now so fingers crossed email gets through.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have 
CNAME for mail.ipimagine.com

But there's no mail.ipimagine.com A record.

So CNAME uses an existing A record, that doesn't exist.

I'd correct all "mail" record to use the "webmail" (if this webmail is the name of the server so all MX should be pointing at it).

Comment: the point is that MAIL is not there defined as a 'A record', so you would need to create it, or maybe just change the mail for "webmail"

Comment: I've just updated the DNS to the last image in the question, I think that should work.

Comment: I've search for the page. your certificate SSL is for the @ .
So the MX is good now.
But just remove that Webmail, since you're SSL doesn't contain that in any subdomain.
www.ipimagine.com redirects to ipimagine.com, so the MX should be preference 0 since there are no other mail or MX record there. And remove the webmail as explained

Comment: if mx points to the domain itself....there's no need for an mx